# How to disable autocomplete but keep autosuggestion using GlazedLists?

Tags: java, glazedlists

This code makes an autocomplete and autosuggestion box for me:

```
if (dataAutoCompleteSearch != null) {
        autoCompleteSupport = AutoCompleteSupport.install(jComboBox1, GlazedLists.eventListOf(dataAutoCompleteSearch));
}
```

The problem occurs when I search for names that contain UTF-8 characters that are not in the data, but start with a few words in the suggestion box.
I could not type these UTF-8 words correctly because the text was added by itself (blue highlighted).

I want to disable GlazedLists autocomplete (Auto add highlighted text when typing) because it is very difficult to type a UTF-8 character.
But I want to keep the suggestion box, looking like Google search.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No. The API of `AutoCompleteSupport` doesn't support this option. You'd basically have to roll your own version of AutoCompleteSupport (it's all open source) and modify it yourself to stop the auto-complete part. I've just had a quick peak at it and it's quite large and I don't have an immediate solution to offer. It'll probably require a bit of experimenting. The private [`AutoCompleteFilter`](https://github.com/glazedlists/glazedlists/blob/master/core/src/main/java/ca/odell/glazedlists/swing/AutoCompleteSupport.java#L1380) class would be my first place to start looking at.

Comment: It's not a pleasure to hear this because I'm not a java expert. I tried to modify insertString method but cannot